# Regarding countdown latch implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have been going through the program which starts three threads and print their corresponding value such that `T3` is executed first, then the `T1` thread, and lastly the `T2` thread is executed. Below is the program.

I just want to know if you guys could help in converting this program with respect to countdown latch, as I want to develop it using this mechanism or it can be also done through counting semaphore.

From the [answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030159/836214):

```
    public class Test {
  static class Printer implements Runnable {
    private final int from;
    private final int to;
    private Thread joinThread;

    Printer(int from, int to, Thread joinThread) {
      this.from = from;
      this.to = to;
      this.joinThread = joinThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      if(joinThread != null) {
        try {
          joinThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* ignore for test purposes */ }
      }
      for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread T3 = new Thread(new Printer(10, 15, null));
    Thread T1 = new Thread(new Printer(1, 5, T3));
    Thread T2 = new Thread(new Printer(6, 10, T1));
    T1.start();
    T2.start();
    T3.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: @LouisWasserman, probably not very much, since he copied it from an answer given to him in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029703/regarding-starting-the-threads-on-a-condition. But you're not helping too much as that's pretty much the only comment I see you posting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

We consider each pair of threads `Tw, Ts` such as `Tw` is waiting on `Ts` to commence its work. In your setup, there are 2 such pairs:

```
T1, T3
T2, T1
```

For each pair, we will create one `CountDownLatch`, and provide it to each thread of the pair. Then `Tw` will call `await` on the latch before starting its work, and `Ts` will call `countDown` at the end of its own work.

Since `T1` belongs to both pairs, it will receive both latches. However, in the first case, `T1` is a waiting thread, and in the second, `T1` is a signaling thread, therefore its code will have to be amended accordingly.

Of course you will have to remove the `join` calls and related infrastructure.

Since your question title asks about latch implementation, let's just briefly say that the same semantics can be produced using a `Semaphore` initialized at `0`, and where `countDown` would actually be a `release` of the semaphore, while `await` would be an `acquire` of that semaphore.

```
public class Test {
  private CountdownLatch latch;
  private Runnable runnable;
  class Tw implements Runnable {
     Tw(CountdownLatch l, Runnable r) {
        latch = l;
        runnable = r;
     }
     @override
     public void run(){
       latch.await();
       runnable.run();
     }
  }

  class Ts implements Runnable {
     CountdownLatch latch;
     Runnable runnable;
     Ts(CountdownLatch l, Runnable r){
        latch = l;
        runnable = r;
     }
     @override
     public void run(){
       runnable.run();
       latch.countDown();
     }
  }

  static class Printer implements Runnable {
    private final int from;
    private final int to;

    Printer(int from, int to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    CountdownLatch l31 = new CountdownLatch(1), l12 = new CountdownLatch(1);    
    Thread T3 = new Thread(new Ts(l31, new Printer(10, 15, null)));
    Thread T1 = new Thread(new Tw(l31, new Ts(l12, new Printer(1, 5, T3))));
    Thread T2 = new Thread(new Tw(l12, new Printer(6, 10, T1)));
    T1.start();
    T2.start();
    T3.start();
  }
}
```

The proposed sample implementation uses auxiliary runnables to take care of the latching process, thus allowing us to compose each task using these runnables, instead of deriving the `Printer` class for each specific case (we save at least one class).

The `Semaphore` based similar implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: could you please the code of this implementation so that I can understand it fully and completely, Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the code of semaphore also that will be a great 8 help to understand

Comment: that's about all you'll get asaimc. I suggest you try reading the faq before asking more questions.